# Magento 2.3 images in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value vs catalog_product_entity_varchar

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images

When we update images programmatically, we see correct images in admin, but not in shop frontend.

Correct images are saved to *catalog_product_entity_media_gallery*.

But magento shop frontend shows still old images.

Also in *catalog_product_entity_varchar* there are still the old images.

Here is the code we use for delete old images:

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
  unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);
```

and here is the code for uploading the new one:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($copyFile, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Code to see the files:

```
$objectManager->get("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler")->execute($product);
$productImages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();   
foreach ($productImages as $image) {
  print "local= <img src='" . $imageData['url'] . "' /> ";
}
```

Why does the code change only the admin media gallery, but not the shop frontend images for Magento 2.3.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like in your code of remove product gallery images, it's not hit all the required media gallery tables in the database. I suggest you follow the below links for this:

**Remove and add gallery images for the product:** 
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-images-to-product-programmatically-magento-2.html

**Or for delete gallery images for the product, check below code:**

```
$gallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
if (count($gallery) > 0) {
foreach($gallery as $image){
$this->productGallery->deleteGallery($image->getValueId());
}
$_product->setMediaGalleryEntries([]);
$_product->save();
}
```

**For a better understanding of Product media images DB tables, check the below link:**
https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-product-images-are-saved-in-database-magento-2/

Comment: Adding additional $product->save(); after saving productRepository solves all problems. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to resolve the issue
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-images-to-product-programmatically-magento-2.html

it's working well i verified this on my local :)